# Nesting API calls and mapping to same returned object ES6 / ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nested, es6-promise, foursquare

I'm just starting out with React and ES6 so apologies if this is a bit of a simple one.

I'm currently playing round with the FoursquareAPI. I'm using ES6 fetch to return a series of objects (they're actually different venues in different parts of the world) which are then mapped and returned and stored in the application's state. This works fine and returns what I want:

```
// method to call api
getVenues: (searchTerm) => {
    const fetchVenuesURL = `${urlExplore}${searchTerm}&limit=10&client_id=${clientId}&client_secret=${clientSecret}&v=20180602`;

return fetch(fetchVenuesURL).then( response => {
         return response.json();
    }).then( jsonResponse => {
        if (jsonResponse.response.groups[0].items) {
            return jsonResponse.response.groups[0].items.map(item => (

                // populate venues
                {
                    id: item.venue.id,
                    name: item.venue.name,
                    address : item.venue.location.address,
                    city : item.venue.location.city,
                    country : item.venue.location.country,
                    icon : item.venue.categories[0].icon
                }

            ));                

        } else {
            return [];
        }

    });

// method in App.js to setState

search(term){
    Foursquare.getVenues(term).then(foursquareResponse => { 
       this.setState({venues: foursquareResponse});
    }); 
}
```

The problem arises when I need to fetch photographs associated with each of the 'venues' returned by the original fetch. These come from a different endpoint. I'm not sure what the best approach is.

One way would be to have two separate api calling methods and then somehow populate an empty photos field of the first with the photos from the second back in App.js but that seems clunky.

My instinct is to somehow nest the Api calls but I'm uncertain about how to go about this. I'm hoping to do something along the lines of somehow applying a method to each iteration of the first mapped object, something along the lines of but not sure how to link them together so that the second goes into the photo property of the first:

```
{
    id: item.venue.id,
    name: item.venue.name,
    address : item.venue.location.address,
    city : item.venue.location.city,
    country : item.venue.location.country,
    icon : item.venue.categories[0].icon
    photos : []
 }

 const fetchPhotosURL = `${urlPhotos}${venueId}/photos?limit=10&client_id=${clientId}&client_secret=${clientSecret}&v=20180602`;

return fetch(fetchPhotosURL).then( response => {
     return response.json();
}).then( jsonResponse => {

    if (jsonResponse.response.photos.items) {
        console.log(jsonResponse.response.photos.items[0].venue)
        return jsonResponse.response.photos.items.map(item => (
        {
            id : item.id,
            created: item.createdAt,
            prefix: item.prefix,
            suffix: item.suffix,
            width: item.width,
            height: item.height,
            venue: item.venue
        }
        ));
    } else {
        return [];
    }
})
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction with this. I'm guessing that it's one of those things that isn't that hard once you've done it once but I'm finding it difficult.

Thanks in advance.